# Adding varnish to existing node Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, varnish

I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json ./
USER node
RUN npm install
COPY --chown=node:node . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]
```

Now I would like to add the Varnish cache and consider this repo [docker-varnish](https://github.com/manios/docker-varnish) how can I organise both together?

**UPDATE 1**

Once I run this command `docker compose build` it show following information, but I don't see anything related to varnish

> [+] Building 4.6s (11/11) FINISHED
> => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                         0.1s  => => transferring dockerfile: 362B                                                                                                                                                         0.0s  => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                            0.1s  => => transferring context: 174B                                                                                                                                                            0.0s  => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:10-alpine                                                                                                                            4.0s  => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                            0.1s  => => transferring context: 21.58kB                                                                                                                                                         0.0s  => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/node:10-alpine@sha256:dc98dac24efd4254f75976c40bce46944697a110d06ce7fa47e7268470cf2e28
> 0.0s  => CACHED [2/6] RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
> 0.0s  => CACHED [3/6] WORKDIR /home/node/app                                                                                                                                                      0.0s  => CACHED [4/6] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                                                                                       0.0s  => CACHED [5/6] RUN npm install                                                                                                                                                             0.0s  => [6/6] COPY --chown=node:node . .                                                                                                                                                         0.1s  => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                       0.1s  => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s  => => writing image sha256:7eec4ec76dbff93f8b0ebc6e03051331709d5f55a641be379a3e00697eabde70
> 0.0s  => => naming to docker.io/library/test_project_node

Am I doing things right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `docker compose` to orchestrate multiple containers, as described here: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/running-varnish-docker/#6-docker-compose .

This uses the official Varnish images, rather than the one you suggested.

Here's an example of such a `docker-compose.yml` file that is used by the `docker compose` command:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  varnish:
    image: varnish:stable
    container_name: varnish
    volumes:
      - "./default.vcl:/etc/varnish/default.vcl"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    tmpfs:
      - /var/lib/varnish:exec
    environment:
      - VARNISH_SIZE=2G  
    depends_on:
      - "node" 
  node:
    build: ./
    container_name: node
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

This `docker-compose.yml` file assumes that it is located in the same folder as the `Dockerfile` for your Node container. It also assumes that `default.vcl` is also located in that folder.

Run `docker compose up` to bootstrap the stack.

Comment: Could you please check my updated question?

Comment: @overflow Don't update questions with additional follow up questions. If this answered your initial question, upvote and mark it as accepted. If not, don't. If you have more question, make a new question and leave this one as is.

Comment: @overflow I updated my answer and added `docker compose up` as the command you'll need to bootstrap the entire stack.